# How to use Jquery to remove classes from all elements with a wildcard

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am making a responsive website. For the mobile version, I am using jQuery mobile, which adds lots of classes to my HTML. I don't want these classes for the Desktop version.

All the jQuery mobile classes  are prefixed with "ui". Although I can use `.removeClass('')`, I would have to use a separate `.removeClass('')` deceleration for each class and for each HTML element.

How can I use a wildcard approach to remove all classes that start with ui, regardless of which element they are on?

I found a plugin called [jQuery alterClass](https://gist.github.com/1517285), which is supposed to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've followed the instructions exactly, but it wont remove the classes. I have set up a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/acyJT/).

Comment: what method are you using to determine whether to remove classes or not? Why not use same method to redirect desktop/mobile version? Or perhaps a better explanation of what the underlying problem is with having classes in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your fiddle,**
Your anchor tag has id: `<a id="#foo"`

You are referring it it in JQuery as `$('#foo')`.
That refers to an element with `id = foo`.

(**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acyJT/1/)**)

Comment: @zerkms This is with respect to his fiddle.

Comment: oops, now I see what you meant :-S

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I made such a simple mistake!

Answer (score 0):

This should remove any class that starts with `ui` on any element, it's not very efficient, and you should consider passing a more specific selector.

Sometimes jQuery UI/mobile will add classes after the DOM is loaded, so just running this once after document ready does'nt guarantee that `ui` classes won't show up again:

```
$('*').attr('class', function(i, classes) {
    return classes.replace(/\sui[^\s]*|^ui[^\s]*/gi, '');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/acyJT/2/)

I would seriously consider finding another way to do this, such as just not including the library if the site is'nt the mobile version etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get all classes starting with UI you can use this. [Beginning exactly with a given string](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
//handles classes like UI1, UI2 ...
$('[class^="UI"]')
```

You can read more on [Jquery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: And this removes the class how ?

Comment: @adeneo This $('[class^="UI"]') selects all elems matching the wildcard. You can use .removeClass() after that or set new value to class with .prop("class","something")

Comment: Actually the class would be an attribute, not a property, so `attr()` would be the correct jQuery method, not `prop()`. I do realize that this selects any element with a class that starts with `ui`, but you'll remove all classes by using `removeClass()`, not just the ones which starts with `ui`, but it's not very clear in the question if that is what the OP is after. I read it as wanting to remove any class starting with `ui` on any element, which this will do, including any other class the elements may have?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the classes from all the elements that have a class starting with `UI`:

```
$('[class^=UI]').removeClass();
```